# Why should I use NIO (or frameworks like netty) instead of java executors?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, nio, executors

Just recently, I learnt about NIO. What I understood is that the main advantage of NIO is we can handle many connections with only one (or few) threads thanks to non-blocking feature of NIO. But can't we achieve this goal using Executors and having a list of worker threads?

I cannot see any advantage of NIO over Executors. Instead, I think executors are better than using NIO as reading messages is very easy and we only need call readLin() for example, but in NIO we should check if the message is partial or the buffer has several messages.

The feature of non-blocking exists in the soul of executors too, where we call execute function of an executor, we are basically add the connection to a buffer and waiting for the fixed number of thread to be free.

So, why would someone use NIO instead of using executors?

Thanks

Comment: You can't handle multiple blocking sockets in a single thread. Hiding behind an `Executor' doesn't change that.

Comment: If I call execute method of the executor for each socket received and have a executor with only one thread, this thread handle these sockets one by one. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. You will block in the first read you issue.

Comment: I am afraid, but you are wrong my friend. I just checked it. It works very well. 

I did this: I created a MessageHandler class that implements Runnable, and is a echo server.  
Then I created a executor: 
ExecutorService executor  = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

Then I created a serverSocket that upon receiving a connection create a MessageHandler and sends the socket to it and using execute function adds it to the executor. 

I connected to the server three times using the client code. The server only echo the first client, others receive echo when I turn the first client off.

Comment: I am not wrong. It is just as I said. You are blocking in `read()` until data arrives, which means you can't service any other threads concurrently in that thread, which is why the second and third clients blocked until the first one finished, which is not want you want.

Comment: NB there's no reason not to use `Executors`, but using a fixed sized thread pool is going to limit concurrency, and your fixed size of 1 is going to limit it concurrency to zero.

Comment: I know, it was just for sake of test. Why I would use 1 thread?

Comment: *I* don't know. Why *did* you use one thread? And why did you claim it disproved my comment, when it didn't? Several mysteries here, all of your devising.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threading is as fast as(or even faster than) NIO until you encounter the scalability issue. Too many threads makes the performance lower than NIO.

But in some cases it was said that multi-threading blocking IO is still better than NIO:http://paultyma.blogspot.com/2008/03/writing-java-multithreaded-servers.html

Comment: That's actually not what he asked about. He asked about NIO versus an executor with a fixed number of threads, and in his comments he strangely used a fixed size of 1.

Comment: You are right considering his propose.  For the title of his question, I think it's still relevant though.   Thanks for your comments and let me clarify that I'm talking about creating a thread per connection here.